# How to create serial number

Tags: php, mysql

form.php

```
<div> Leaving From 
<input type="text" class="from" name="source_point" id="source_point" title="Departure Place" required/>
</div>
<div class="right"><b>Going To
<input type="text" class="to" name="destination" id="destination" title="Arrival Place" required />
</div>
```

search.php

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>Sl No.</td>
<td>Bus Operator</td>
<td>Bus No. </td>
 </tr> 

 <?php
$s=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM  bus_detail where source_point='$_SESSION[source_point]' && destination_point='$_SESSION[destination]'");
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($s))
{
?>

 <tr>
<td>   </td>
<td><?php echo $row['bus_name'];?> </td>

<td><?php echo $row['bus_no'];?></td> 
</tr>
<?php }?>
</table>
```

I want to display serial numbers from 1 according to the search results,  in the empty `<td>` field, not any random number.. It should be serial numbers in proper format ...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is as simple as adding a counter variable.

```
 <?php
$s=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM  bus_detail where source_point='$_SESSION[source_point]' && destination_point='$_SESSION[destination]'");
$counter = 0;
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($s))
{
?>    
 <tr>
<td><?php echo ++$counter; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['bus_name'];?> </td>    
<td><?php echo $row['bus_no'];?></td> 
</tr>
<?php }?>
```

You need to go through the basics if you couldn't figure this out.

Comment: thank u.. i knew abt the count variable bt i wasnt sure.. now its fine.. thank u

Comment: can anybody know how to display the serial number in descending order?

Answer (score 1):

You can add incremental value inside the loop

In your search.php, include

```
$i=1;
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($s))
{
?>

<tr>
<td><?php echo $i   </td>
<td><?php echo $row['bus_name'];?> </td>

<td><?php echo $row['bus_no'];?></td> 
</tr>
<?php $i++ }?>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

user a count variable as initialize with 0 and increment it by 1 in each row display and you can print the serial no as this way.

```
  <table>
<tr>
<td>Sl No.</td>
<td>Bus Operator</td>
<td>Bus No. </td>
 </tr>




     <?php
$count = 0;
    $s=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM  bus_detail where source_point='$_SESSION[source_point]' && destination_point='$_SESSION[destination]'");
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($s))
    {
    $count+=1;
    ?>

     <tr>
    <td><?php echo $count; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['bus_name'];?> </td>

    <td><?php echo $row['bus_no'];?></td> 
    </tr>
<?php }?>
</table>
```